# minimum required Android versions for apps whose support "varies by device"

Tags: android, google-play

I am researching what minimum versions of Android OS are required by popular apps in the Google Play store, but I'm having trouble finding that information for certain apps whose minimum OS version "varies by device", as in this screenshot of the Facebook app:

[image]

I know I can answer my question by exhaustively attempting to install the apps on devices running different OS versions, but this would be a monumental task if, say, you wanted to find out the minimum version for a list of 10 apps.

Is there an easy way to find out what the minimum Android version is for different device models in Google Play?

Comment: `Is there an easy way to find out what the minimum Android version is for the Facebook app in Google Play?` No. there is not. If facebok not provides, what version you need for app, then you could not find it out somewhere in web.

Comment: @anatoli, that's a fair answer.  If you create an answer with this, I'll mark it as the answer, if it holds up to the scrutiny of other SO users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no proper way of getting all data for all devices. I found some info about how Google Play makes this data available here: https://developer.android.com/google/play/filters#filtering-on-the-google-play-web-site.

So there is no better way than to try with different devices. One possible way of making this less tedious is to log in with a Google account on multiple devices (you can even log in on emulated devices) running different Android versions. You should then see which devices from your list support an app on the app's page on the Google Play website.

**Original answer:**

When I open an app's page in chrome on Windows, I can just scroll down and see
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION -> Requires Android -> x.x and up

I think inside the Google Play app itself, you can only find apps your device (on which Google Play is installed) supports.

Comment: Yes, for *some* apps, I see the minimum version, but not *all* apps.  For example, look at Facebook.

And yes - that's how it works - Google Play only shows you apps compatible with your device.  But that doesn't solve my problem.  (See my last comment in the original post.)

Comment: You're right. Well it probably means what it says. Maybe there is no real way to define "minimum version" of apps that do this.

Comment: Yeah, I think it makes sense that it can vary by device,  For example, on Samsung model X, we require version 8.0+, but on model Y, we support version 9.0+.  Totally fair, and Google Play supports this configuration.  You can even drop support for certain models entirely.

Comment: I appreciate your constructive feedback - I have updated my question, with refinement.

Comment: I tried to find some official info about this and the most accurate thing I found is https://developer.android.com/google/play/filters#filtering-on-the-google-play-web-site
So you could create an account with all devices you care about (you could just sing in with that account in an emulator representing desired device) and just look at the store website. If you wanted to do this on a large scale, this would probably be worth it. Unfortunately, I think there is no proper solution.

Comment: thanks for this creative idea.  I was able to do this using my physical devices, and it works - the web page tells me which of my devices it will work on.  And using emulated Android devices makes it feasible.  I'd just need to create an emulated device for each models and OS version that I'm interested in, and then add it to my Google account.  It's still a time-consuming task, but it's one solution to the problem.  In the absence of other answers, I'd accept this.  Edit your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

When you creates new project in `Android Studio`, there you can find the versions, with that you can create an app

[image]

Also you can look in [version distribution](https://www.appbrain.com/stats/top-android-sdk-versions) to see, what versions are currently in use.

And in wikipedia you can look, which verisons are supported and what name is what API level

[image]

With support of 26+ you will create an app for almost 80% of all android users (at april 2021)

Comment: @tele-bird, what do you then mean with `popular apps`? Do you want create one app or is it just for recearch? With smaller version you can support more devices. thats all.

Comment: My goal in asking this question is not how to create an app that supports a certain OS version.  Rather, just to find out what minimum OS version is required for apps on the market.  The problem is: for apps whose minimum OS version "varies by device", there's no way to know without actually trying it on numerous devices, which is impractical.